# If I reset windows will it keep my EFS Certificate?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, reset, efs

I've having issues with BSOD when I try to boot. Before I make a lenghty post about trying to fix that I was wondering if I use the 'Reset my PC' option if this will still allow me to access my enrypted EFS files afterwards?

I have no backup of the EFS certificate and it wasn't until I tried to access the files on another machine that I realised they were encrypted.

The files are exrtemely important, any help will be appreciated.

I've also tried to export the EFS Certificate from CMD in the Recovery Options but I got the error "the cipher command is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: I suggest decrypting the files before the Reset. How did you export the certificate?

Comment: I can't do tht unfortunately because I didn't export the certificate. I've tried to export the certificate as advised in the post but I've been unable to do that as well.

Comment: I added a method for exporting the certificate.

Comment: The answer to your question is, no, you will not keep your EFS certificate if you Reset Windows

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my post but I can't get into windows at all. I get a BSOD when i try to boot and I'm also getting BSOD when trying to boot into safe mode (SYSTEM THREAD EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED - asmtxhci.sys). I've tried to extract the EFC Certificate from WindowsPE in the Recovery environment but I get the error "the cipher command is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @ramhound thanks, do you know how I can extract the certificate in anyway? currently I can only get into Windows PE due to BSOD.

Comment: You cannot export the EFS outside of Windows and specifically if your unable to log into the user who created the certificate. If your unable to log into the user who created the EFS certificate then the file encrypted by that certificate can be considered lost.  When you created the certificate you were prompted to export and backup the certificate. Your question should contain that information about the BSOD, would have saved harry some time writing an answer, that cannot be performed if they had know your unable to boot into Windows

Comment: @Ramhound yes I cannot seem to locate the back up file and don't remember even saving it it was so long ago. From the recovery environment > advanced options > command promt it asks me to login and I can successfully login, i think this WinPE?

Comment: @harrymc apologies for not being clear in my initial post! It's my first time and quite stressed

Comment: Since WinPE does not have certmgr.msc you are out of luck

Comment: As long as the files are still there on disk (that is, all the Registry files and the AppData contents), there are programs that "export" them offline through WinPE.

Comment: @user1686 Can you recommend any? I have all the files I just can't get into windows

Answer (score 2):

To export your private key (must be logged-in as the user that
encrypted the files, which is lost when resetting Windows):

- Run `certmgr.msc`
- Open "Personal"
- Click on "Certificates"
- Click on "Intended Purposes" to sort by the column
- Scroll down and double-click the entry with the Intended Purpose of
  "Encrypting File System"
- Position to the tab of "Details"
- Click "Copy to File..."
- Click Next
- Select "Yes, export the private key" and click Next
- Click Next (leave all selected options)
- Select "Password" and enter the password twice
- Click Next
- Select folder and file-name and click Next
- Click Finish.

Comment: If you can't login as the user that encrypted the files, the encryption key is effectively lost.

Comment: +1 eventhough you miss the first paragraph of your post explaining that its not possible to access the files after the reset my pc function because then the certificate is lost, so the only way to solve this is by exporting the certiticate from the current install only. So technically, you are not answering the question.

Comment: @LPChip: I strengthened the condition, as after Reset the user is lost and so is the certificate.

Comment: @LouisHarrison: before resetting Windows, try [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).